# MS Access 2007 Report - Spanning Row and Column in Tabular Layout

Tags: ms-access-2007, html-table

How to span a row and column in tabular layout like below:

```
---------------------
     |     Name     |
 ID  | --------------
     | First | Last |
---------------------
```

Sorry for this newbie question

Thanks before

Comment: In what are you trying to do this? Tables or queries, you can't. Forms and reports, you can.

Comment: (Report) see the title. it seem impossible with tabular layout but yes in manual way.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It's quite simple. First create your report in tabular format, then modify the report to put the fields where you want them. You can rearrange the fields however you want. So you start out with:

```
--------------------------
 ID | Name| First | Last |
--------------------------
```

Then just move First & Last underneath Name, so you get:

```
---------------------
     |     Name     |
 ID  | --------------
     | First | Last |
---------------------
```

If you're asking if there's an automatic way, then no.